# Vncviewer Size is too Small

Tags: vnc

My Windows XP (on a laptop with a 12" monitor) is running the vncserver and I have a RedHat (on a desktop with a 19" monitor) running the vncviewer. The vncserver is 4.1.3.

When I run the vncviewer, the size of the vncviewer seems to about 12" only which is like the size of my laptop. I want to make it bigger possibly the size of my desktop monitor.

I tried to google around for an answer and found this: http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2008-February/058725.html

But I think his setup is the opposite (Linux as the vncserver and Windows as the vncviewer). Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3):

vnc -geometry widthxlength e.g.
`vnc -geometry 1240x980`
is good for 1280x1024 with some room for the VNC viewer's border.

Comment: Where do I add this? On the Windows side (vncserver)? Something like this? "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\winvnc4.exe" -noconsole -geometry 1240x980

The above didn't work.

When I tried to do vncviewer -geometry 1240x980  on my Redhat, that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

vncserver -geometry 1920x1080, on Linux, does make the second screen of VNC Viewer on Windows come up larger, but has no effect on the first screen to appear on Windows that is asking for the VNC Server on Linux.  That screen is puny, has the "About"/"Options"/"Connect" buttons cut off, and these instructions have no effect on that first screen.
If you're looking for solution to the screen you'd use the most, this works. If you're looking for the solution to the puny login screen, this has no effect on that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The VNC program comes with scaling. I use Ultra VNC and in the options it has *Scale to window*. With this I can make it as big as I want and it strecthes the image.